# Name of cartoon-like font in this image?

Tags: font-identification

I have a logo that I need to recreate. But I am unable to find out the fonts used in the logo. This is a logo for fire cracker company.

[image]

Comment: Hi Habib, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please provide a screenshot of the logo? Without that, we can't help you. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase.  Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: I have uploaded the image file. :) Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Need the Fireworks text font and Dizzy Dean's font

Comment: Don't know the name of the "Fireworks" font but I'm sire it's the same as the font used for the Xbox game "Cel Damage" http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Celdamagebox.jpg

Comment: This is not a font name. That was the text i am talking about.

Comment: Can you please tell me the font name

Comment: Have you been to any sites?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "fireworks" would be [baby kruffy](http://www.dafont.com/baby-kruffy.font?text=FIREWORKS) font:

[image]

==============

The "dizzy dean's" would be [ironman font](http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/I/Ironman.html):

[image]